# Swapping column values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, logic

I was solving one of the puzzles and came across swapping column values using DML queries:

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE;
ID1, ID2
--------
20, 15
20, 15
20, 15
```

Solution is mathematical calculation:

```
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE SET ID1=ID1+ID2;
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE SET ID2=ID1-ID2;
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE SET ID1=ID1-ID2;
```

Now, I am trying to figure out whether this can be applied to Strings or not, please suggest.

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE_NEW;
ID1, ID2
--------
ABC, XYZ
ABC, XYZ
ABC, XYZ
```

Comment: What should be output?

Comment: TechDo, ID1 should contain all ID2 values and vice-versa. In this case  ID1 values should be XYZ and ID2 values should be ABC.

Comment: Why you want to swap values instead of column names??

Comment: I am trying to learn DML queries.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's no need to have three update statements, one is sufficient:

```
UPDATE temp_table_new 
SET    id1 = id2, 
       id2 = id1;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make both column the same value?

Comment: @Mihai: no: the values on the right side of the `=` are the old values, regardless, if they are being set in the statement.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Thanks ,do you know if this is also the case for other dbms?

Comment: @Mihai: only if you use MySQL, but not for other DBMS

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Names
(
F_NAME VARCHAR(22),
L_NAME VARCHAR(22)
);

INSERT INTO Names VALUES('Ashutosh', 'Singh'),('Anshuman','Singh'),('Manu', 'Singh');

UPDATE Names N1 , Names N2 SET N1.F_NAME = N2.L_NAME , N1.L_NAME = N2.F_NAME 
WHERE N1.F_NAME = N2.F_NAME;

SELECT * FROM Names;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Before:

```
select * from employ;

EMPNO FNAME      LNAME
----- ---------- ----------
 1001 kiran      kumar

 1002 santosh    reddy


update employ e set fname=(select lname from employ where empno=e.empno),
                    lname=(select fname from employ where empno=e.empno);
```

#### After:

```
 select * from employ;

 EMPNO FNAME      LNAME
------ ---------- ----------
  1001 kumar      kiran

  1002 reddy      santosh
```