# How can i Swap two values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have the following data.

```
TRACK_ID      CT_ID           IMAGE_SORT_NO       IMAGE_LEVEL
132071        63461               1                image_1
132081        63461               2                image_2
132091        63461               3                image_3
```

Image_sort_no is a primary key. Each image_sort_no has a picture. I have to swap the values of 1 to 3 and 3 to 1. My expected output looks like

```
TRACK_ID      CT_ID           IMAGE_SORT_NO       IMAGE_LEVEL
132071        63461               1                image_3
132081        63461               2                image_2
132091        63461               3                image_1
```

If I run the following update statement then I lose the image_level of 1.

```
Update cd_offender
   set image_level = image_3
 Where IMAGE_SORT_NO = 1;
```

How can I swap the values without losing anything?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827804/swapping-column-values-in-oracle

Comment: I don't want to do hard coded. In simple I have to swap first value with last value.

Comment: How about if there are 4 or 5 or more records for each ct_id? Just the first and last to be swapped?

Comment: Yes, just need to swap first and last.

Comment: So, image_sort_no would not just be 1-3 but can have more? In between first and last, image_level will not change?

Comment: Please mark the correct answer below in order for this inquiry to be closed. TY

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
With xxx As (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT IMAGE_SORT_NO As min_sort_no, 
           IMAGE_LEVEL As min_IMAGE_LEVEL
    FROM cd_offender
    ORDER BY IMAGE_SORT_NO LIMIT 1
  ) x
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT IMAGE_SORT_NO As max_sort_no, 
           IMAGE_LEVEL As max_IMAGE_LEVEL
    FROM cd_offender
    ORDER BY IMAGE_SORT_NO DESC LIMIT 1
  ) y
)
UPDATE cd_offender t
SET IMAGE_LEVEL = CASE
    WHEN IMAGE_SORT_NO = xxx.min_sort_no THEN xxx.max_image_level
    WHEN IMAGE_SORT_NO = xxx.max_sort_no THEN xxx.min_image_level
    ELSE IMAGE_LEVEL -- just to be on the safe side
END
FROM xxx
WHERE IMAGE_SORT_NO IN (xxx.min_sort_no, xxx.max_sort_no )
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8e19d/6

Answer (score 0):

This will swap the values of image_level between the first and last value only

```
SELECT t1.track_id,
       t1.ct_id,
       t1.image_sort_no,
       CASE WHEN t1.image_sort_no = t2.firstsort THEN t2.firstvalue
            WHEN t1.image_sort_no = t2.lastsort THEN t2.lastvalue
            ELSE t1.image_level
        END image_level
  FROM cd_offender t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ct_id,       
                          MAX(image_sort_no) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY image_sort_no) firstsort,
                          MAX(image_level) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY image_sort_no) firstvalue,
                          MAX(image_sort_no) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY image_sort_no) lastsort,
                          MAX(image_level) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY image_sort_no) lastvalue
                     FROM cd_offender
                    GROUP BY ct_id) t2
    ON t1.ct_id = t2.ct_id
 ORDER BY t1.ct_id,
          t1.track_id,       
          t1.image_sort_no;
```

To UPDATE

```
MERGE INTO cd_offender 
USING 
(
  SELECT t1.track_id,
       t1.ct_id,
       t1.image_sort_no,
       CASE WHEN t1.image_sort_no = t2.firstsort THEN t2.firstvalue
            WHEN t1.image_sort_no = t2.lastsort THEN t2.lastvalue
            ELSE t1.image_level
        END image_level
  FROM cd_offender t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ct_id,       
                          MAX(image_sort_no) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY image_sort_no) firstsort,
                          MAX(image_level) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY image_sort_no) firstvalue,
                          MAX(image_sort_no) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY image_sort_no) lastsort,
                          MAX(image_level) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY image_sort_no) lastvalue
                     FROM cd_offender
                    GROUP BY ct_id) t2
    ON t1.ct_id = t2.ct_id
 ORDER BY t1.ct_id,
          t1.track_id,       
          t1.image_sort_no
) ta  ON (ta.track_id = t_image.track_id
     AND ta.ct_id = t_image.ct_id
     AND ta.image_sort_no = t_image.image_sort_no)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
   SET t_image.image_level = ta.image_level;
```

Comment: Yup this query is working. But how can I update my table using this query?